# Android 9 "battery fully charged" icon flickers: What does it mean?

Tags: battery, 9.0-pie, samsung-galaxy-s-10

With my Samsung S10e phone fully charged, when I unplug it from USB then re-plug it in, the "battery fully charged" behaves like this:

- appears and disappears a few time quickly
- stays visible for 5 seconds
- appears and disappears a few time quickly
- stays visible for 5 5seconds
- appears and disappears a few time quickly
- stays visible forever

Question: What does that mean exactly? In particular, is it an indication that there is a kind of problem with the hardware or software?

[image: battery fully charged icon Android 9]

Comment: https://www.androidauthority.com/maximize-battery-life-882395/ its a common software issue on many roms, no need to worry about

Comment: @alecxs: I read the entire article, it talks about how to maximize battery life. Would you mind explaining how it relates to the flickering/visible cycle I observed, and what ROMs do not cause that? If possible as an answer rather than a comment, so that people can vote on it. Thanks :-)

Comment: it is not related. Not sure if there is a list with ROMs, just my experience. it's a software loop, it disconnects charging when full, then it connects and start charging. Bad side effect: it also kicks adb shell every ~5 seconds. I have seen this many times