# USB disconnects on Samsung Galaxy A51

Tags: samsung, usb, usb-debugging, android-10, developer-options

I have Samsung Galaxy A51 (SM A515F) running latest official Android 10 and macOS 10.15 development machine.

ADB authorization is given, but sometimes (~ once per 30 minutes) it disconnects and shows the dialog again.

It happens only with this device (I have ~10 different devices). I've tried different USB ports and cables (including one that was shipped with device) with no luck.

I see the device in the ioreg output:

```
SAMSUNG_Android@00400000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x100fbd4da, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (2 ms), retain 18>
```

But not in the `adb devices` output:

```
$ adb devices   
List of devices attached
```

It connects again only after few repeatedly accepted dialogs and re-connection.

How to fix it?

UPD. Now it just periodically disconnects and reconnects, sometimes with prompt, sometimes without it.

Logs at the disconnection time (removed unrelated lines):

```
06-16 18:04:54.650 12533 13319 D SDHMS:com.sec.android.sdhms.thermal.siop.y: SIOP:: AP:261(261,0) BAT:263(263,0) CHG:263(263,0) USB:0(0,0) WIFI:209(260,50) LRP:268(268,0) LRF:266(266) LRB:268(268) 
06-16 18:04:54.758 18551   346 I adbd    : USB event: FUNCTIONFS_SUSPEND
06-16 18:04:54.953   361   389 E libmtp  : [mtp_simple_sink_thread : 0315] -->[mtp_simple_sink_thread, 315] !!!!!! read failed errno [5], error [I/O error]
06-16 18:04:54.954 18551   346 I adbd    : USB event: FUNCTIONFS_DISABLE
06-16 18:04:54.955  4571  4596 D DataRouter: After the usb select
06-16 18:04:54.955  4571  4596 D DataRouter: read length is zero
06-16 18:04:54.955  4571  4596 D DataRouter: dr_usb_deinit
06-16 18:04:54.956  4571  4596 D DataRouter: dr_usb_init
06-16 18:04:54.956  5019  5749 V UsbDeviceManager: USB UEVENT: {SUBSYSTEM=android_usb, SEQNUM=9235, ACTION=change, USB_STATE=DISCONNECTED, DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/android_usb/android0}
06-16 18:04:54.956  4571  4596 E DataRouter: USB Interface is open with 0x6
06-16 18:04:54.956  4571  4596 D DataRouter: USB interface is now configured for usb_fd = 0x6
06-16 18:04:54.956   361   389 E libmtp  : [mtp_simple_sink_thread : 0362] -->[mtp_simple_sink_thread 362] read error [0] [Success]
06-16 18:04:54.957  5019  5749 D UsbDeviceManager: updateState: state=DISCONNECTED
06-16 18:04:54.957  4571  4596 D DataRouter: Before the usb select
06-16 18:04:54.958   361   361 W MTPRx   : notification from stack 21
06-16 18:04:54.959   361   361 W MTPRx   : Read Error Came so calling usbRemoved()
06-16 18:04:54.962 18551   358 I adbd    : UsbFfs: connection terminated: read 39577 failed with error Cannot send after transport endpoint shutdown
06-16 18:04:54.962   361   361 D MTPRx   : MTP_RUNNING_STATUS = 1
06-16 18:04:54.964 18551 18551 I adbd    : UsbFfs: offline
06-16 18:04:54.968   361   361 D MTPRx   : battery status : Full
06-16 18:04:54.969   361   361 D MTPRx   : usb data role status : host [device]
06-16 18:04:54.969   361   361 D MTPRx   :  sendbooster is false!
06-16 18:04:54.969   361   361 D MTPRx   : In usbRemoved Status bar enabled
06-16 18:04:54.970  5019 13123 D SettingsProvider: isChangeAllowed() : name = mtp_running_status
06-16 18:04:54.973   361   361 D MTPRx   : inside finishSync
06-16 18:04:54.974  5019 13123 D SettingsProvider: isChangeAllowed() : name = mtp_sync_alive
06-16 18:04:54.974  5019  5019 V SettingsProvider: Notifying for 0: content://settings/system/mtp_running_status
06-16 18:04:54.990   361   361 I MTPRx   : action : A, selection : 0, update : 0
06-16 18:04:54.995   361   361 I MTPRx   : action : D, selection : 0, update : 0
06-16 18:04:54.996   361   361 I MTPRx   : It's not file transfer case. skip scan.
06-16 18:04:54.998  5019 13123 D SettingsProvider: isChangeAllowed() : name = mtp_drive_display
06-16 18:04:55.000  5019  5019 V SettingsProvider: Notifying for 0: content://settings/system/mtp_drive_display
06-16 18:04:55.001  5019 13123 D SettingsProvider: isChangeAllowed() : name = mtp_sync_alive
06-16 18:04:55.003  5019 13123 D SettingsProvider: isChangeAllowed() : name = mtp_open_session
06-16 18:04:55.005  5019 13123 D SettingsProvider: isChangeAllowed() : name = mtp_event_status
06-16 18:04:55.007   361   361 W ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.stopService:1644 android.content.ContextWrapper.stopService:693 android.content.ContextWrapper.stopService:693 com.samsung.android.MtpApplication.MtpReceiver.usbRemoved:959 com.samsung.android.MtpApplication.MtpReceiver$1.handleMessage:623 
06-16 18:04:55.012   361   361 E MtpService: onDestroy.
06-16 18:04:55.021   361   361 E MtpService: Unregister Mtp disable Receiver
06-16 18:04:55.023   361   361 E MtpService: Receiver not registered: com.samsung.android.MtpApplication.MtpService$1@1fdfbaa
06-16 18:04:55.023   361   361 E MtpService: Unregister mtpEmergencyReceiver
06-16 18:04:55.023   361   361 E MtpService: Receiver not registered: com.samsung.android.MtpApplication.MtpService$2@b4e239b
06-16 18:04:55.024   361   361 E MtpService: unregistering mtpUserPresentReceiver in UnregisterAllIntent
06-16 18:04:55.024   361   361 E MtpService: Receiver not registered: com.samsung.android.MtpApplication.MtpService$4@58afe95
06-16 18:04:55.024   361   361 E MTPJNIInterface: noti = 103
06-16 18:04:55.026   361   361 E libmtp  : [mtp_usb_mtp_finalize : 1207] -->****** [mtp_usb_mtp_finalize 1207] mtp_close_fd Calling 
06-16 18:04:55.026   361   361 E libmtp  : [mtp_close_fd : 0118] -->[mtp_close_fd 118]  fd = 63...
06-16 18:04:55.027   361   361 E libmtp  : [mtp_close_fd : 0126] -->[mtp_close_fd 126] USB endpoint [63] closed...
06-16 18:04:55.027   361   361 E libmtp  : [mtp_usb_mtp_finalize : 1210] -->****** [mtp_usb_mtp_finalize 1210] Updating the gInitializeFlag Flag to FALSE 
06-16 18:04:55.027   361   361 E libmtp  : [mtp_usb_mtp_finalize : 1213] -->****** [mtp_usb_mtp_finalize 1213] Calling mtp_stop_io 
06-16 18:04:55.078  5019 13123 I ActivityManager: Process com.samsung.android.MtpApplication (pid 361) has died: fore SVC (133,1457)
06-16 18:04:55.078  4473  4473 I Zygote  : Process 361 exited due to signal 9 (Killed)
06-16 18:04:55.079  5019  5079 I libprocessgroup: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 1000 pid 361 in 0ms

.....

06-16 18:05:02.373  5019  5749 V UsbDeviceManager: USB UEVENT: {SUBSYSTEM=android_usb, SEQNUM=9236, ACTION=change, USB_STATE=CONNECTED, DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/android_usb/android0}
06-16 18:05:02.374  5019  5749 D UsbDeviceManager: updateState: state=CONNECTED
06-16 18:05:02.375  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: handleMessage -> MSG_UPDATE_STATE: connected=1 configured=0 mCurrentFunctions=mtp,adb
06-16 18:05:02.376 18551 18551 I adbd    : ADB disconnect
06-16 18:05:02.376  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: updateUsbNotification(false): mConnected=true mConfigured=false mCurrentFunctions=mtp,adb mHostConnected=false mSourcePower=false mSinkPower=true mUsbCharging=true mUseUsbNotification=true
06-16 18:05:02.377 18551 18551 I adbd    : destroying transport UsbFfs
06-16 18:05:02.377  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: Set mCurrentFunctionsForNoti=mtp
06-16 18:05:02.378  5019  5065 D DexObserverFW: isDexModeOn() : false
06-16 18:05:02.379  5019  5065 D DexObserverFW: isSemiDexModeOn() : false
06-16 18:05:02.379  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: id=27 mUsbNotificationId=0
06-16 18:05:02.380 18551 18551 I adbd    : UsbFfsConnection being destroyed
06-16 18:05:02.387  5019 11795 D AdbDebuggingManager: Received disconnected message: 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 rankor@Artems-iMac.local
06-16 18:05:02.388  5019  5749 V UsbDeviceManager: USB UEVENT: {SUBSYSTEM=android_usb, SEQNUM=9237, ACTION=change, USB_STATE=CONFIGURED, DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/android_usb/android0}
06-16 18:05:02.388  5019  5749 D UsbDeviceManager: updateState: state=CONFIGURED
06-16 18:05:02.400  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: updateUsbNotification notifyAsUser: id=0 title=USB for file transfer
06-16 18:05:02.401  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: updateUsbStateBroadcastIfNeeded: remainingFunctions=5
06-16 18:05:02.402  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: broadcasting Intent { act=android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE flg=0x31000000 (has extras) } extras: Bundle[{host_connected=false, connected=true, unlocked=true, config_changed=false, adb=true, mtp=true, configured=false}]
06-16 18:05:02.404  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: sending intent ACTION_USB_STATE: connected=true configured=false mCurrentFunctions=5 mHostConnected=false
06-16 18:05:02.406  5019  5065 D AdbDebuggingManager: Logging key 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 rankor@Artems-iMac.local, state = 7, alwaysAllow = true, lastConnectionTime = 1592319902404, authWindow = 604800000
06-16 18:05:02.407  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: handleMessage -> MSG_UPDATE_STATE: connected=1 configured=1 mCurrentFunctions=mtp,adb
06-16 18:05:02.408  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: updateUsbNotification(false): mConnected=true mConfigured=true mCurrentFunctions=mtp,adb mHostConnected=false mSourcePower=false mSinkPower=true mUsbCharging=true mUseUsbNotification=true
06-16 18:05:02.409  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: Set mCurrentFunctionsForNoti=mtp
06-16 18:05:02.409  5019  5065 D DexObserverFW: isDexModeOn() : false
06-16 18:05:02.410  5019  5065 D DexObserverFW: isSemiDexModeOn() : false
06-16 18:05:02.411  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: id=27 mUsbNotificationId=27
06-16 18:05:02.411  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: updateUsbStateBroadcastIfNeeded: remainingFunctions=5
06-16 18:05:02.412  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: broadcasting Intent { act=android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE flg=0x31000000 (has extras) } extras: Bundle[{host_connected=false, connected=true, unlocked=true, config_changed=false, adb=true, mtp=true, configured=true}]
06-16 18:05:02.423 18551 18564 I adbd    : opening control endpoint /dev/usb-ffs/adb/ep0
06-16 18:05:02.425  4571  4596 D DataRouter: After the usb select
06-16 18:05:02.425  4571  4596 D DataRouter: read length is zero
06-16 18:05:02.425  4571  4596 D DataRouter: dr_usb_deinit
06-16 18:05:02.425  5019  5749 V UsbDeviceManager: USB UEVENT: {SUBSYSTEM=android_usb, SEQNUM=9239, ACTION=change, USB_STATE=DISCONNECTED, DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/android_usb/android0}
06-16 18:05:02.425  4571  4596 D DataRouter: dr_usb_init
06-16 18:05:02.426  5019  5749 D UsbDeviceManager: updateState: state=DISCONNECTED
06-16 18:05:02.426  4571  4596 E DataRouter: USB Interface is open with 0x6
06-16 18:05:02.426  4571  4596 D DataRouter: USB interface is now configured for usb_fd = 0x6
06-16 18:05:02.426  4571  4596 D DataRouter: Before the usb select
06-16 18:05:02.433  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: sending intent ACTION_USB_STATE: connected=true configured=true mCurrentFunctions=5 mHostConnected=false
06-16 18:05:02.439 18551 18564 I adbd    : UsbFfsConnection constructed
06-16 18:05:02.441  3319  3319 D MTPRx   : In MtpReceiverandroid.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE
06-16 18:05:02.504 18551  3364 I adbd    : USB event: FUNCTIONFS_BIND
06-16 18:05:02.524  3319  3319 I MTPRx   : getUsbdebugStatus is false
06-16 18:05:03.460 18551 18551 W adbd    : timeout expired while flushing socket, closing
06-16 18:05:03.929  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: handleMessage -> MSG_UPDATE_STATE: connected=0 configured=0 mCurrentFunctions=mtp,adb
06-16 18:05:03.930  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: updateUsbNotification(false): mConnected=false mConfigured=false mCurrentFunctions=mtp,adb mHostConnected=false mSourcePower=false mSinkPower=true mUsbCharging=true mUseUsbNotification=true
06-16 18:05:03.931  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: Set mCurrentFunctionsForNoti=mtp
06-16 18:05:03.932  5019  5065 D DexObserverFW: isDexModeOn() : false
06-16 18:05:03.932  5019  5065 D DexObserverFW: isSemiDexModeOn() : false
06-16 18:05:03.933  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: id=0 mUsbNotificationId=27
06-16 18:05:03.934  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: updateUsbNotification cancelAsUser: id=27
06-16 18:05:03.935  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: updateUsbStateBroadcastIfNeeded: remainingFunctions=5
06-16 18:05:03.935  5019  5019 D EdgeLightingManager: isCallingUserSupported : callingUserId=-1, mUserId=0, isDualAppId=false
06-16 18:05:03.935  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: broadcasting Intent { act=android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE flg=0x31000000 (has extras) } extras: Bundle[{host_connected=false, connected=false, unlocked=true, config_changed=false, adb=true, mtp=true, configured=false}]
06-16 18:05:03.937  5019  5019 D LightsService: [api] [SvcLED] turnOff:: id = 4 (uid: 1000 pid: 5019) 
06-16 18:05:03.937  5019  5019 D LightsService: [api] [SvcLED] LED indicator : Not supported.
06-16 18:05:03.940  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: sending intent ACTION_USB_STATE: connected=false configured=false mCurrentFunctions=5 mHostConnected=false
06-16 18:05:03.943  5019  5019 D UsbMirrorLinkManager: !usbConnected
06-16 18:05:03.951  5019  5065 D KnoxCustomManagerService: getUsbConnectionTypeInternal(0)
06-16 18:05:03.951  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: getPersistProp: return=persist.sys.usb.config
06-16 18:05:03.952  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: ANAWAY_JIG_PATH is not exist.
06-16 18:05:03.953  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: setEnabledFunctions: usbFunctions=mtp,adb forceRestart=false usbDataUnlocked=true mCurrentFunctions=mtp,adb
06-16 18:05:03.953  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: setEnabledFunctions: Before validation LONG[5]
06-16 18:05:03.954  5019  5065 D SecContentProvider: query(), uri = 17 selection = isUsbDebuggingEnabled
06-16 18:05:03.954  5019  5065 D SecContentProvider: called from android.uid.system:1000
06-16 18:05:03.955  5019  5065 D RestrictionPolicy: isUsbDebuggingEnabled : true
06-16 18:05:03.955  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: policy : adb, restrict(allow) = true
06-16 18:05:03.962  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: setEnabledFunctions: After validation STR[mtp,adb], LONG[5]
06-16 18:05:03.963  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: trySetEnabledFunctions: usbFunctions=mtp,adb forceRestart=false
06-16 18:05:04.032  3319  3319 E libmtp  : [mtp_usb_mtp_finalize : 1207] -->****** [mtp_usb_mtp_finalize 1207] mtp_close_fd Calling 
06-16 18:05:04.032  3319  3319 E libmtp  : [mtp_close_fd : 0118] -->[mtp_close_fd 118]  fd = 63...
06-16 18:05:04.032  3319  3319 E libmtp  : [mtp_close_fd : 0126] -->[mtp_close_fd 126] USB endpoint [63] closed...
06-16 18:05:04.032  3319  3319 E libmtp  : [mtp_usb_mtp_finalize : 1210] -->****** [mtp_usb_mtp_finalize 1210] Updating the gInitializeFlag Flag to FALSE 
06-16 18:05:04.032  3319  3319 E libmtp  : [mtp_usb_mtp_finalize : 1213] -->****** [mtp_usb_mtp_finalize 1213] Calling mtp_stop_io 
06-16 18:05:04.049 12533 12558 W System  : A resource failed to call close. 
06-16 18:05:05.255  5019  5749 V UsbDeviceManager: USB UEVENT: {SUBSYSTEM=android_usb, SEQNUM=9241, ACTION=change, USB_STATE=CONNECTED, DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/android_usb/android0}
06-16 18:05:05.257  5019  5749 D UsbDeviceManager: updateState: state=CONNECTED
06-16 18:05:05.258 18551  3364 I adbd    : USB event: FUNCTIONFS_ENABLE
06-16 18:05:05.258  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: handleMessage -> MSG_UPDATE_STATE: connected=1 configured=0 mCurrentFunctions=mtp,adb
06-16 18:05:05.259  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: updateUsbNotification(false): mConnected=true mConfigured=false mCurrentFunctions=mtp,adb mHostConnected=false mSourcePower=false mSinkPower=true mUsbCharging=true mUseUsbNotification=true
06-16 18:05:05.260  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: Set mCurrentFunctionsForNoti=mtp
06-16 18:05:05.261  5019  5065 D DexObserverFW: isDexModeOn() : false
06-16 18:05:05.262  5019  5749 V UsbDeviceManager: USB UEVENT: {SUBSYSTEM=android_usb, SEQNUM=9242, ACTION=change, USB_STATE=CONFIGURED, DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/android_usb/android0}
06-16 18:05:05.263  5019  5749 D UsbDeviceManager: updateState: state=CONFIGURED
06-16 18:05:05.270  5019  5065 D DexObserverFW: isSemiDexModeOn() : false
06-16 18:05:05.271  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: id=27 mUsbNotificationId=0
06-16 18:05:05.284  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: updateUsbNotification notifyAsUser: id=0 title=USB for file transfer
06-16 18:05:05.286  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: updateUsbStateBroadcastIfNeeded: remainingFunctions=5
06-16 18:05:05.286  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: broadcasting Intent { act=android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE flg=0x31000000 (has extras) } extras: Bundle[{host_connected=false, connected=true, unlocked=true, config_changed=false, adb=true, mtp=true, configured=false}]
06-16 18:05:05.289  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: sending intent ACTION_USB_STATE: connected=true configured=false mCurrentFunctions=5 mHostConnected=false
06-16 18:05:05.289  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: handleMessage -> MSG_UPDATE_STATE: connected=1 configured=1 mCurrentFunctions=mtp,adb
06-16 18:05:05.290  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: updateUsbNotification(false): mConnected=true mConfigured=true mCurrentFunctions=mtp,adb mHostConnected=false mSourcePower=false mSinkPower=true mUsbCharging=true mUseUsbNotification=true
06-16 18:05:05.290  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: Set mCurrentFunctionsForNoti=mtp
06-16 18:05:05.291  5019  5065 D DexObserverFW: isDexModeOn() : false
06-16 18:05:05.291  5019  5065 D DexObserverFW: isSemiDexModeOn() : false
06-16 18:05:05.292  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: id=27 mUsbNotificationId=27
06-16 18:05:05.293  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: updateUsbStateBroadcastIfNeeded: remainingFunctions=5
06-16 18:05:05.294  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: broadcasting Intent { act=android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE flg=0x31000000 (has extras) } extras: Bundle[{host_connected=false, connected=true, unlocked=true, config_changed=false, adb=true, mtp=true, configured=true}]
06-16 18:05:05.304  5019  5077 I ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationExternalStorageWhitelisted:com.samsung.android.MtpApplication user:0
06-16 18:05:05.304  5019  5077 D ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationExternalStorageWhitelisted: DO is not enabled on user 0. Allowed.
06-16 18:05:05.304  5019  5077 D ActivityManager: package  com.samsung.android.MtpApplication, user - 0 is SDcard whitelisted
06-16 18:05:05.304  5019  5077 I ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationExternalStorageBlacklisted:com.samsung.android.MtpApplication user:0
06-16 18:05:05.304  5019  5077 D ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationExternalStorageBlacklisted: DO is not enabled on user 0. Allowed.
06-16 18:05:05.304  5019  5077 I ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationExternalStorageBlacklisted:com.samsung.android.MtpApplication user:0
06-16 18:05:05.304  5019  5077 D ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationExternalStorageBlacklisted: DO is not enabled on user 0. Allowed.
06-16 18:05:05.309  5019  5065 D UsbDeviceManager: sending intent ACTION_USB_STATE: connected=true configured=true mCurrentFunctions=5 mHostConnected=false
06-16 18:05:05.314 18551 18551 I adbd    : UsbFfs: already offline
06-16 18:05:05.315 18551 18551 I adbd    : Calling send_auth_request...
06-16 18:05:05.319 18551 18551 I adbd    : Loading keys from /data/misc/adb/adb_keys
06-16 18:05:05.321 18551 18551 I adbd    : adb client authorized
```

Comment: After accepting ADB authorization permanently have you tried to disconnect and reconnect USB cable to that device to see if the authorization was saved correctly? If it is saved try to reboot the device if the authorization persists a reboot.

Comment: @Robert yes, it saves state fine between normal reconnections

Comment: Then my only guess would be that adb daemon on-device crashes, restarts and there is a timing problem that the adb daemon first starts and then reads it's allowed devices configuration. But if the config is read the dialog has already been shown.

Comment: @Robert currently I guess that Vysor app may crash the daemon. I've removed it, will watch for the issue

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/215817 https://android.stackexchange.com/q/215869